# IntelliJ idea Embeded H2 database client connection Error: Database may be already in use: null

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, h2

[image]1. I have a simple spring boot Microservice with CRUD operation with an H2 in file database

spring boot datasource URL property
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./src/db/fleet`

I want to access database using IntelliJ idea but I am getting below error

[90020][90020] Database may be already in use: null. Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-210]

Answer (score 2):

The reason was: Spring boot start database in embedded mode. In embedded mode if some other process try to access database then we will get above mentioned error.

Solution:
Step 1. Start the database in Mixed mode. as below

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./src/db/fleet;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE`[image]

Step 2. IntelliJ idea database client configuration with type `URL only` and use the exact spring datasource URL in URL field